# Git synchro with remote

Tags: git

I got a local sandbox branch and a remote sandbox branch.

But, my local sandbox isn't very clean.
I might have 41 commits late, and 10 in advance.

I want to wipe out all my commits in advance to be able to pull the remote sandbox without any merge commit.

Should I go for a git pull with some option or the hard way and reset head by 10 commits ?

Thanks

Comment: git pull should sync your local with remote `git pull origin sandbox `

Comment: No because I have commit in advance and I don't want to keep them.

Comment: It sounds like you want to discard your 10 commits. If that's the case, `reset` is the way to go.

Comment: Yes it is. But i want to get something clean I mean, I dont want the flow reverting the commits. May be reset is what I'm looking for, I'll go check the documentation

Comment: ok, then do **hard reset** local with remote, `git fetch; git reset --hard orgin/sandbox`

Comment: `git reset --hard HEAD~10` is what I need then ?

Comment: Yes, but after that need to pull origin sanbox to get latest 41 commits locally. By `git fetch; git reset --hard origin/sandbox` command your local sandbox will be replaced with remote/sanbox

Comment: Can someone post an answer to allows the question being marked as solved ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do *hard reset* by origin/sandbox then, local *sandbox* will be replaced with *origin/sandbox*.

```
$ git fetch
$ git reset --hard origin/sandbox
```

Or, discard last 10 commits of local *sandbox* then, Pull *origin/sandbox* to get the latest commits (41 commits) of remote *sandbox*.

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD~10
$ git pull origin sandbox
```